# Best way to store large amounts of text data?

Tags: c#, file-io, text-files

I am planning on building a 'data file' that my new game loads, this file contains a whole lot of text (we are talking about 300-400, maybe even double that, paragraphs) along with some trivial data. Basically, what would be the best way of storing this data in a file.
   There are a few requirements:

1. backward/forward compatible (be able to gracefully accept older data and recognize new data(
2. encryptable (so something like sqlite would be bad?)
3. lightweight and quick to load
4. possibly with some sort of anti-corruption recovery sector.

Basically, is there anything out there that fits my needs? or is it going to be a 'roll-your-own' situation (no problem with either). If it's a roll-my-own, what would you recommend.

I pretty much threw XML out of the window (far too 'bulky' and complex), was thinking of something like a virtual file-system, with a 'location-table' for quick reading of the data.

I'm pretty curious what other programmers have to say.

Comment: Just like to add, I would also like to store some LUA scripts aswell. If that changes anything

Comment: did you look into JSON?
http://www.json.org/example.html
it's has most of the things XML has to offer but without so much of the the syntactic noise.
http://www.json.org/fatfree.html

Comment: Enumerate your requirements concisely and then measure them against what is available. Other than the "anti-corruption" feature you may or may not need, an XML file seems like it would be idea. Encryptable, compressable, could potentially be worked on outside of the game environment. And 600-800 paragraphs is not a large file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry that you threw out XML. It's pretty easy to work with once you get the hang of it, and when you do it's a skill that carries with you from job to job.

Honestly, XML is how I would do it. I'm using Java for my game, not c#, but regardless, all the quest text and NPC interaction is stored in XML.

Comment: XML seems to add a huge amount of 'overhead' to the file though? I agree it satisfies all my criteria, but i just don't know. If you know any really really really easy way of handling it in C#, then you might sell it to me :)

Comment: LINQ to XML is a great technology for interacting with XML.  Have a look at this page for a '5 minute overview' to give you a sense of how you can use it. http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx

Comment: also would like to store some lua scripts in there.

Comment: @R4000: Have you proved the overhead to be a problem in your application?  At what point does the overhead become an issue?  If your answers are no/I don't know then you are optimizing prematurely in this case.

Comment: @Ed S. thats fair enough, but in this case I have decided I also need to store LUA scripts along with some of the XML, I imagine this is not recommend? and I dont really want to split into 2 files

Comment: Well, the overhead of XML is really just the overhead of the syntax, i.e., it takes more characters to store `<SomeTag>Data</SomeTag>` than it does to store `SomeTag:Data`.  You may run into special character problems with the lua script.  Why not store the script in a separate file and simply store the path to it in the XML?

Comment: I agree with @Ed for storing the LUA. Put each script in their own file, and reference them with an XML tag.

Answer (score 2):

XML and JSON are both pretty good formats for storing data, although XML can be more flexible for some applications, and overkill for others.

XML is only 'bulky' if you're editing it by hand a lot and on disk if you're not compressing it. It gzips very well.

Answer (score 0):

You're a bit wrong about 'large' XML overhead. It's no so large as you think while XML provides a great flexibility. Take a look at some XML parsers -- they're really simple.
[.NET XML Best Practices](http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_674.aspx)